# Issue with Google-map infoWindow

Tags: google-maps, pointers, infowindow

I'm developing a Website where i need to show Google-Map with multiple Pin/Pointer. The Pin/Pointer are displaying at proper place as per the latitude and longitude, but when i click on those pins/pointers the infoWindow pointer pointing different place - approx 25px right from the pin/pointer location.

Please help me to get rid of this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide your _code_ if you need help. If you can't do that read the documentation on [custom icons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) and [InfoWindows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)

Comment: You can check the site here... spectrumofteachingstyles.org/NEW2/around-the-world Please view the page source for the JS Stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If so, you need to bind the InfoWindow object to the marker, like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
```

Comment: You can check the site here...

http://spectrumofteachingstyles.org/NEW2/around-the-world/

Please view the page source for the JS Stuff

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was in marker definition. It was wrongly defined.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: feature.position,
    icon: {
        url:icon_img.icon,
        size:new google.maps.Size(62,35),           
        origin:new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor:new google.maps.Point(15,25),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30)
    },
    shape:shape,
    map: map
});
```

The above code was not correct, because the "size" and "scaledSize" property is holding the different value. I changed it to

```
size:new google.maps.Size(30,30)
```

Now the infoWindow is in proper place. Thank you all.